# d3 Filtering data

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have the csv file

```
Crime Category Description, Crime Code, Month Of Arrest
NONE, 123, 1
NONE, 234, 4
THEFT, 333, 4
THEFT, 444, 3
BATTERY, 456, 5
BATTERY, 55, 3
```

I try to filter the data where "Crime Category Description" = "THEFT" and
"Crime Category Description" = "BATTERY".
To do this, I use

```
d3.csv("Urbana_Police_Arrests_Since_1988.csv", function(error,data){
...
.enter().append("rect")
.data(data.filter(function(d){return d.key = "THEFT" && d.key == "BATTERY" }))
```

Unfortunately, it does not work. Any ideea why?

Output should be:

```
THEFT, 333, 4
THEFT, 444, 3
BATTERY, 456, 5
BATTERY, 55, 3
```

Comment: Look at your data: do you think it's possible the crime being `THEFT` **and** `BATTERY`? Besides that, there is no `key` property here. If you have a nest, please post your **exact** data array. On top all that, you should not call `data` **after** appending the element.

Comment: @GerardoFurtado Yes... It looks confusing...that's why I want to remove some data

Comment: So, please edit your question, posting your exact data array and the expected outcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to keep the objects where `Crime Category Description` is `THEFT` **or** `BATTERY`, not `THEFT` **and** `BATTERY`, which is impossible.

Therefore, use the [OR (||) operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators#Logical_operators):

```js
var csv = `Crime Category Description, Crime Code, Month Of Arrest
NONE, 123, 1
NONE, 234, 4
THEFT, 333, 4
THEFT, 444, 3
BATTERY, 456, 5
BATTERY, 55, 3`;

var data = d3.csvParse(csv);

var filtered = data.filter(function(d) {
  return d["Crime Category Description"] === "THEFT" || d["Crime Category Description"] === "BATTERY"
})

console.log(filtered)
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
```